# loop through columns of a df and pick every two columns and concat them and create a new df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large datasheet and I need to take every two columns (i.e., columns 0 and 1, then 4 and 5,..) then concatenate them, and create a new df.
I thought this should work but it's not. Any thoughts?

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\zj\Volume-Sampled Export.csv')
df2=[]

for i in range(len(df. columns)):
    df1=df.loc[:, df.columns[i*4:i*4+1]]
    df2.append(df1)
df2= pd.concat(df2)    

df2.to_csv(r'C:\Users\zj\totalfeed1.csv')
```

Comment: How are the values in the 2 columns to be joined? An example would make your intentions clearer. And why 0+1, 4+5 but not 2+3 - what is the logic used to select which columns.,

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a list in that repeating pattern. Something like this would suffice:

```
n = 20 # df.shape[1]
lst_ = [x for x in range(n) if x % 4< 2]
```

print:

```
[0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 16, 17]
```

After this you can just do: `df.iloc[:, lst_]` to select your dataframe columns